# Sequelize port unchangeable

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, docker, sequelize.js

I'm writing an application using node with sequelize, docker and mysql. When trying to connect to sequelize I'm somehow limited to using port 3306, if I change the port in "config.db.details" I get the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.5:3300
```

When connecting to sequelize I use the following configurations:

```
config.db = {
    user: 'root',
    password: 'pass',
    name: 'ticketgo'
};

config.db.details = {
    host: 'database',
    port: 3300
};
```

Docker.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  client:
    build: ./client
    ports:
     - "3001:3000"
    volumes:
     - "./client:/app"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=ticketgo.local

  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
     - "./server/src:/app/src"
    links: 
     - "database"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=api.ticketgo.local

  database:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "ticketgo"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pass"
    volumes:
     - "./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"

  adminer:
    image: "adminer"
    ports:
     - "4444:8080"
    links:
     - "database"
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Need set port for database:

```
database:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "ticketgo"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pass"
    volumes:
     - "./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    ports:
     - "3306:3300"
```